# OutOfMemoryError in LogService of Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, profiling, java.util.logging

I'm using Google App Engine v.1.9.1, Java edition, running inside Eclipse Kepler SR2. I've got JDK 1.7. My logging.properties is sending the logs to the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` only.

My [edit] development server running in Eclipse [/edit] receives a lot of data from another server and just dumps it into a database. This generates a lot of logs. I get OutOfMemoryError after only a few hours.

I've run JProfiler and I figured out the object being kept around is `com.google.apphosting.api.logservice.LogServicePb$LogLine`. Somehow this isn't being discarded, ever, keeping millions of instances in memory.

Sure I can reduce the amount of data logged but that will only delay the problem.

I've looked everywhere to figure out how to flush out the log lines but I can't find any setting for this. The only option available is for Python not Java.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Dev server is not designed to handle production loads. Do you see the same error in production?

Comment: @PeterKnego I just started development. We don't have a production server yet. The "load" in question is running for one minute per hour and there's only about 200 database queries. This is far from a big load. Yes there are lots of log statements, but why are they just not discarded from memory? If I reduce the log statements it will only delay the problem for a few days before it'll crash again.

Comment: The development server is not intended to be as "production quality" as your application requires.  It is only a small subset of the production cloud environment for limited testing.  Create an Application Id online, deploy you application, and monitor its logging activities and memory usage up there for at least 24 hours.  If the deployed server leaks memory, you have a big [bug to report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Type%3DDefect).  If only your local development environment leaks memory, you have a little bug to report.

Comment: @PeterKnego just to mention, in GAE admin panel one can control access so that only desired Gmail accounts can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Martin Berends said, the development server inside Eclipse is only for developing. It seems that log statements are kept in memory in that environment. Once I moved my app to a test server, the memory usage seems to be flat.

So the bottom line is; when running in a development environment, reduce the amount of logging and restart the server once in a while to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`s. Secondly, do your tests on a real test server.